# Round Off time to the upcoming nearest 15 minutes time using Groovy

Tags: datetime, groovy, soapui, rounding

I am trying to round off time to the upcoming 15 minutes time.
e.g :

1. `2017-12-11T13:11:51.728Z` to `2017-12-11T13:15:00.000Z`
2. `2017-12-11T13:21:51.728Z` to `2017-12-11T13:30:00.000Z`

**Groovy code :**

```
def currentTime = context.expand('${#Project#currentTime}')
log.info currentTime
date1 =  new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'").parse(currentTime)
//Round off the time nearest to the mod 15
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.setTime(date1);
int unroundedMinutes = calendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
int mod = unroundedMinutes % 15;
log.info calendar.add(Calendar.MINUTE, mod < 8 ? -mod : (15-mod));
```

**Output :**

> Mon Dec 11 14:32:32 IST 2017:INFO:2017-12-11T14:32:32.690Z
>   Mon Dec 11 14:32:32 IST 2017:INFO:null

Comment: 'currentTime' is of type String convert this to Date

Comment: After parsing to date, now output is 'null'.

Comment: what you are getting from context.expand('${#Project#currentTime}')?

Comment: It's current datetime : 2017-12-11T13:11:51.728Z

Comment: Are you using Java 8? If so, there are alternative data types to `Date` and `Calendar`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go:

- In order to get the difference minutes, created a closure.
- The closure gets called recursively if needed.
- If the current minutes is divisible by 15, it won't adjust the time; that is the reason for adding third value in the list.
- To be able to test with multiple values, used list of dates. You may use it for single value as well.

```groovy
def timez = ['2017-12-11T13:11:51.728Z', '2017-12-11T13:21:51.728Z', '2017-12-11T13:30:00.000Z']
def dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'"
def roundValue = 15
//Change timezone if needed
def tz = 'IST'

TimeZone.setDefault(TimeZone.getTimeZone(tz))

Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance()

def getNearestMinutes
//Closure which gets called recursive
getNearestMinutes = { cmin, nearMin = roundValue ->
    def tempResult = cmin % nearMin
    if ( tempResult < nearMin && (0 < (nearMin - cmin)) ) {
        return (nearMin - cmin)
    } else { 
        return getNearestMinutes(cmin, nearMin+roundValue) 
    }
}


//Loop thru times and round the time
timez.each {
    calendar.time = Date.parse(dateFormat,it)
    def currentMinute = calendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE)
    def cof = currentMinute % roundValue
    if (cof) {
        currentMinute += getNearestMinutes(currentMinute)
        calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, currentMinute )
    }       
    calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0)
    calendar.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0)
    log.info calendar.time.format(dateFormat)   

}
```

You can quickly try it online <kbd>[demo](https://ideone.com/hA5EGK)</kbd>

**EDIT:** Felt that the solution could be made something more simple than applying above difficult conditions.

*Here is another solution to round time to near future 15 min.*
Yet, easy to read code unlike multiple conditions in the first solution.
This is simple one using `Switch statement`

```groovy
def timez = ['2017-12-11T13:11:51.728Z', '2017-12-11T13:21:51.728Z', '2017-12-11T13:30:00.000Z', '2017-12-11T13:46:00.000Z']
def dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'"
def roundValue = 15
//Change timezone if needed
def tz = 'IST'

TimeZone.setDefault(TimeZone.getTimeZone(tz))

Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance()

def getNexTime = { min ->
  def result
  switch(min) {
    case 1..15: 
        result = 15
        break
    case 16..30:
        result = 30
        break
    case 31..45:
        result = 45
        break
    case 46..60:
        result = 60
        break
    default:
        result = 0
        break
  }
  result
}



//Loop thru times and round the time
timez.each {
    calendar.time = Date.parse(dateFormat,it)
    def currentMinute = calendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE)
    if (0 != getNexTime(currentMinute)) {
        calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, getNexTime(currentMinute) )
    }
    calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0)
    calendar.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0)
    println calendar.time.format(dateFormat)    
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Rao, 
Almost done...i only need output in this format (2017-12-11T13:15:00.000Z).
Seconds and miliseconds should be zero.

Comment: It is update just couple of minutes back check the changes by click in edit link below the solution or take it once again and try or try the demo.

Comment: Perfert. Thanks :)

Comment: @rAJ, Thanks you find it useful. You may see the second solution which is more simple logic.